# Expectation of a R.V times a Constant C.

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

supposed that we have to deal with this expectation:

let X be a R.V. and C some constant.

can we say that:

$E[CX]= E[C]E[X] = CE[X]$

Thanks!

Comment: what's your definition of independence of two r.v ?

Comment: You do not need middle term, $E[CX]=CE[X]$.

Comment: @GabrielRomon there is only one r.v. there!

Comment: Your equality "$E[CX]= E[C]E[X]$" is non-sense then.

Comment: @GabrielRomon How? Doesnt E[C]= C ?

Comment: If there is indeed only *one* r.v. here then @GabrielRomon is correct. In that case your first equality (that shows $\mathsf EC$) makes no sense and must simply be left out.

Comment: Your approach is fine, but more work than it needs to be. An expectation is nothing more than an integral with respect to a certain measure, so it key properties of integrals -- particularly, that $\mathbb E[ c X] = c \mathbb E [X]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say that in the understanding that $C$ following the symbol $\mathsf E$ denotes a random variable prescribed by $\omega\mapsto C$ and is defined on the same probability space as $X$.

In that case $X$ and $C$ are automatically independent random variables and $\mathsf EC=C$ where the LHS is the expectation of a random variable and the RHS is a constant.

That leads to:$$\mathsf ECX=\mathsf EC\mathsf EX=C\mathsf EX$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
EcX=\int cX(w)\, dP(w)=c\int X(w)\,dP(w)=cEX
$$
and
$$
Ec=\int c\,dP=c\int\,dP=c.
$$